# Get Instance of Codeigniter on 404 page

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, http-status-code-404

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

Isn't working on 404 page when there is no controller.

Example: http://www.example.com/asdasd

Is there a workaround so that I can call my `get_instance()` method?

As I need to get some config items in my config file and the uid of the user.

Thanks,

Comment: Update to the latest version and use the 404_override route to point to a controller/action.

Comment: does that mean I will create a custom 404 page?

Comment: In theory, it's just a normal page/route, however CodeIgniter will execute that controller/action should the request not match any other routes.